# How to rank query results when using Q objects

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am building an image database using Django. The user should be able to search for an artwork using its title, the names the artists, its location, etc. I am currently using Q Objects to construct the query:

```
query_search = request.GET.get('search')
terms = [term.strip() for term in query_search.split()]
q_objects = Q()

for term in terms:
    q_objects.add(Q(title__icontains=term), Q.OR)
    artists = Artist.objects.filter(Q(name__istartswith=term) | Q(name__icontains=' ' + term))
    q_objects.add(Q(artists__in=artists), Q.OR)
    q_objects.add(Q(location_of_creation__name__istartswith=term), Q.OR)
    keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
    q_objects.add(Q(keywords__in=keywords), Q.OR)

querysetList = (Artwork.objects.filter(q_objects)
                               .exclude(published=False)
                               .order_by('title',
                                         'location_of_creation',
                                         'artists')
                               .distinct())
```

I would like to order the results by *relevance* (e.g. show title-matches before artist-name-matches).

As far as I understand this is usually accomplished by using annotate(): A ranking number is set and then used by order_by(). However, I am not sure how to do this when using Q objects. Is it possible to "annotate" Q objects? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Case statements. The construction of Q objects with reduce is a bit ugly but the general idea should apply. [Link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
Artwork.objects.annotate(
    rank=Case(
        When(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=term) for term in terms)), then=Value(1)),
        When(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(location_of_creation__name__istartswith=term) for term in terms)), then=Value(2)),
        default=Value(99),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by(
    'rank',
    'title',
    'location_of_creation',
    'artists'
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I put an additional .exclude(rank=99) at the end.